# Subsequent POSTs won't update the content in popup window

Tags: javascript, http-post, browser-cache

The below function opens a new named popup window and the content is posted to that window. 
The problem I am facing is : `**it seems the content is being served from the cache**`.

For example : the params I passed, for the first time, is two I should see the content for 2 parmas in the new window. Second time if I pass 4 parmas I should see the content for 4 paramas but I still see the content for the previous request.  I do see the named popup window getting refreshed but still show old content.

```
function (url, params, target) {
     var form = ['<form method="POST" id= "frmpopup" action="', url, '" target="', target, '">'];
        for (var key in params)
            form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');
        form.push('</form>');
        jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0];

        window.open('', target, "width:500px; height:700px; resi");
        $("#frmpopup").submit();
}
```

Comment: When you say the first time and second time, you are saying that this function is on a page, and you call it twice on that page?

Comment: Not necessarily I call twice. the problem I am facing is the subsequent calls remembers the content of the first call.

Comment: What I am getting at is that if you are using the same page to make all the calls, then there are multiple form controls with the same name on the page, so $('#frmpopup').submit(); acts on the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make sure that there is only one form being submitted.

```
function (url, params, target) {
$('#frmpopup').remove();
 var form = ['<form method="POST" id= "frmpopup" action="', url, '" target="', target, '">'];
    for (var key in params)
        form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');
    form.push('</form>');
    jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0];

    window.open('', target, "width:500px; height:700px; resi");
    $("#frmpopup").submit();
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. I thought from your description you were creating multiple forms on the page.